# RadWindow AlwaysOnTop

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7, radwindow, always-on-top

Does anyone have any experience with the `RadWindow` wpf control from Telerik? 
My problem is that when I open a `RadWindow` and minimize my application then when I maximize the application the `RadWindow` is not visible. I can use alt+tab to get the `RadWindow` in front again, but I would really like to avoid having to do this.
I'm doing the following to display the `RadWindow`:

```
this.theWindow.ShowDialog();
```

Where `theWindow` is an instance of a class that inherits from `RadWindow`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using ShowDialog() and not just Show() ? If you want to have it always on top you can use the TopMost property.

Comment: @jalfp: I'm using ShowDialog because I want the window to be modal. RadWindow does not have a TopMost property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem at the [Telerik forums](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/window/modal-window-not-on-top.aspx). The solution was to set the `Owner` property of the RadWindow to my application's main window.

Comment: Hmmm ok I get it know. I though that the RAD window was your main window. Anyway, using the Owner property is the way to do.